# how to get rid of a raised mole in my left thigh which is painful sometimes?

Tags: removal, melanoma, moles, groin

I am 22 , male. The mole appeared some 3 weeks before . Since last week it is painful sometimes ,not all time . The spot is left thigh near the groin muscle. It is difficult to wear jeans and even other trousers . Can you suggest medicines and is there effective natural ways ( without any side effects ) to remove the annoying mole?

The mole is not symmetrical . are moles cancereous ?

Can moles be completely eliminated ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, moles can definitely be cancerous. They can be malignant melanoma, which is a deadly cancer unless treated early. The fact that it is [asymmetrical](https://www.melanoma.org/understand-melanoma/diagnosing-melanoma/detection-screening/abcdes-melanoma) is not a good sign.

Do not attempt to treat it yourself. That mole needs to be examined by a doctor ASAP.